# Save to sharepoint but getting runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am using the below code to save to a share point and its adapted from a working code that would save to a shared drive

```
ThisFile = Range("AK3").Value
ThisPath = Range("AR21").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With ActiveSheet
Range("B1:AF35").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.add
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisPath & ThisFile & ".xlsm"
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End With
```

Cell AK3 example Concession 869 09.04.21 20.19

Cell AR21 example
//Companyname.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/teams/foldername/Shared%20Documents/Concessions/Concessions?csf=1&web=1&e=iA12As/

The run time error asks that the path is clear of : but they are in the path. is there a way around this?

Comment: Try `ThisPath = Replace(ThisPath,  ":f:/r/", "")`  You may also need to remove the querystring (`?` and everything after that)

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for this. I don't get the error now using the replace but it is not saving on the SharePoint either. I have tried with and without the querystring

Comment: Hi, I got this to work. I recorded the macro in another sheet walking it through the pathway and copied that. I was missing the    _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. I recorded the macro in another sheet walking it through the pathway and copied that. I was missing the
_ , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False